# Módulo requests é importado no IDLE, mas não no Thonny (a IDE que eu uso)

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, python-requests, import

Eu instalei o módulo `requests` pelo Terminal com `sudo pip3 install requests` (estou usando Mac) e consegui importa-lo pelo interactive shell sem problemas no IDLE. Mas quando tento importar pelo interactive shell do Thonny, aparece o seguinte erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

E quando eu tento pelo IDLE...

```
Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5926, Jul 16 2017, 20:11:06) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> WARNING: The version of Tcl/Tk (8.5.9) in use may be unstable.
Visit http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/ for current information.
import requests
>>>
```

O que faço? Se está instalado, porque o IDLE reconhece, mas o Thonny não? O que faço para o Thonny reconhecer? **Não posso usar o IDLE**, porque quando eu coloco acento no IDLE, o IDLE dá "Não respondendo"... Preciso usar o Thonny...

Comment: Provavelmente, a versão do *Python* que o projeto está usando não é a `3.x`

Comment: @WéllingthonM.deSouza Thonny está usando versão 3.6.1, IDLE versão 3.6.2. Rodou no IDLE, não no Thonny. Pode ser isso?

Comment: Pergunta bem básica: você fechou o Thonny e abriu novamente após instalar a biblioteca?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Aham... Já até reinstalei o Thonny. Nesse meio-tempo estava reiniciando a máquina. O problema persiste. Apaguei também o IDLE, mas ainda não o reinstalei. Já tentei também usar o comando `pip` pro `requests` de novo, mas deu tudo `Requirement already satisfied`.

Comment: 1º não faz sentido o "tenho que usar o Thonny", afinal você deve precisar é executar o trabalho. 2º verifique se vc está usando virtualenv e se o path para as lib's que essa IDE estranha está usando é o mesmo do terminal. OBS: aconselho migrar para o VSCode..

Answer (score 0):

Ola!

Na maioria dos IDE's ( **Integrated Development Environment** ) possui a opção  de escolher qual interpretador sera usado,normalmente essa definição fica na barra superior do ide.

Caso o ide não tenha essa escolha pode talvez encontrar em uma nova versão, outra situação que o ide pegue uma versão diferente da linguagem a qual não precise é que no teu sistema operacional esteja instalado uma versão padrão da linguagem.

Não é indicado mudar o padrão da linguagem , o sistema pode estar usando alguma função e mudando de versão podera dar algum erro no sistema.

Encontrei essa pagina do [thonny.org](https://thonny.org/blog/) que mostra outras versões do ide.
Em relação ao problema dos acentos, o IDLE pode estar usando um utf que não seja compatível ao linguagem "pt-br", e IDLE dispõem dessa configuração seja no IDE ou diretamente no script dessa forma podendo usar caracteres sem que ocorra erro de encoding